# How to get, store and reuse firebase token in cypress api automated testing

Tags: firebase, api, automation, token, cypress

after sending in body "email" and "password" https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/ returns a few objects in the response.
One of them is "idToken": with a value of the token.

What do I need?

I need to get this token, store it in variable and reuse it in further tests.

So far I prepared something like this:

````
        it("Get a fresh admin firebase token", () => {
            cy.request({
                method: "POST",
                url: "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/...",
                body: {
                    "email": "myUsername",
                    "password": "myPassword",
                    "returnSecureToken": true
                },
                headers: {
                    accept: "application/json"
                }
            }).then((responseToLog) => {
                cy.log(JSON.stringify(responseToLog.body))
            }).then(($response) => {
                expect($response.status).to.eq(200);
        })
    })
})```

Above code works, but cy.log() returns the whole body response. How can I separate only idToken and reuse it in my next API scenarios?
````

Comment: So is `idToken` present in the response body ?

Comment: Yes, it is. But this idToken is one of 8 objects in the response. So how can I separate/get only this token and reuse it?

By 8 objects I mean:
"kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
    "localId": 
    "email": 
    "displayName": 
    "idToken": 
    "registered":
    "refreshToken": 
    "expiresIn":

I am getting chain of characters with all of the data in response.
I tried to use e.g.
cy.log(JSON.stringify(responseToLog.body[1]))
but it returns only empty log in the console.

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `idToken` in in response body so inside `then()` you can directly wrap the value and save it using an alias and then use it later.

```js
it('Get a fresh admin firebase token', () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/...',
    body: {
      email: 'myUsername',
      password: 'myPassword',
      returnSecureToken: true,
    },
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json',
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    cy.wrap(response.body.idToken).as('token')
  })
})

cy.get('@token').then((token) => {
  cy.log(token) //logs token or Do anything with token here
})
```

In case you want to use the token in a different `it` block you can:

```js
describe('Test Suite', () => {
  var token
  it('Get a fresh admin firebase token', () => {
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/...',
      body: {
        email: 'myUsername',
        password: 'myPassword',
        returnSecureToken: true,
      },
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      token = response.body.idToken
    })
  })

  it('Use the token here', () => {
    cy.log(token) //prints token
    //use token here
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you Alapan. It works. 
But now I am not sure how to transfer this @token to the another test
I tried:
```it("Get some details", () => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "My url"
            headers: {
              'Authorization': this token should be here
            },
      })```

So I want to get details from the body of some different endpoint using previously obtained token. Should I create any var or something to store this token and reuse it in the next test in the headers: {Authorization: ""} ?

Sorry for bad formatting.

Comment: Do you intend to used it in a different `it()`block or the same `it()`?

Comment: Different block. For all the endpoints I want to use different it() block

Comment: Thank you so much Alapan! It was really helpfull.